# Stimulsoft is not supported by my server

Tags: asp.net, stimulsoft

I create some reports and use them in my website, after upload the report, I contact with my host provider, and they told me that they not support stimulsoft

What can I now to do ?!!
Is there anybody out there to help me ?!!

Regards ,
Ali Foroughi

Comment: Copying the Stimulsoft's DLLS to the bin folder should take care of everything as long as the DLLs don't have any extra dependencies, like a service or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no other way to do that , so I change my strategy and start to using crystal report

Comment: What problem do you have found in putting all the DLL in your BIN folder? Just curious.

Comment: @Steve , No the only solution is install this component on the server , and because our host provider does not support this component we decide to use crystal report and putting DLL in to the bin folder does not resolve my problem about this stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux server then your hoster is right.
Stimulsoft Reports based on .Net Framework which needs IIS server.